# Word boundry not working in MySQL 8.0.16 REGEX?

Tags: mysql, regex, mysql-8.0, word-boundary, word-boundaries

I am baffled...I am using MYSQL 8.0.16 and according to the manual a simple word boundry, \b, should work. But it wont work...

my query:

```
SELECT *
FROM  `wp_posts` 
   WHERE (post_title REGEXP '\bUSD\b' 
    )
   AND post_type = 'post'
```

I am using mySQL 8.0.16 and I also tested it on 8.0.18, with same results...

help appreciated

cheers

ben

Comment: You need to escape the backslash: `\\b`

Comment: `\b` in a string is the backspace character, you need a literal backslash.

Comment: brilliant!! thanks so much :) it works

Comment: I don't think `123USD` does not have a "word boundary" before `USD`.